# Is it possible to get the controller name in the output of Symfony2's router:debug command?

Tags: symfony

The Symfony2 console command `router:debug` produces a list of all the currently configured routes, including the name, HTTP method and pattern for each route.

Is it possible to also get the controller for each route in this list, without resorting to using `router:debug [name]` for each route and parsing out the controller from the "Defaults     _controller:" line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining the RouterDebugCommand class showed that this wasn't possible, so I made a change to the outputRoutes method: https://gist.github.com/3380250

Comment: Nice job, but consider moving the command to one of your bundles. Set the command name to the old one and in theory it should overwrite it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. I've updated the linked Gist to show the new command.